# Is there a public list of the PS4 games I own?

Tags: ps4

Now a lot of people are working from home, I want to share a list of the PS4 games I can play at lunchtime with my colleagues.

Is there an easy way to do this?

A public list (like Steam can do) would be best, but even if I have to copy-paste the list from my online PlayStation account, that would be better than trying to type them all.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Download List**

If I understand Corsaka's answer correctly, he is correct to say that you can go to your [download list](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/download/list) after logging into your PS Account on the PS Store. But I do not recommend this route. As far as I am aware, there are many cons to this page with what you are requesting:

- Non-public (requires you to be logged into **your** account to view)
- Lists everything you download: Patches, DLCs, Expansions, Themes, etc...
- Not user friendly and extremely hard to find things, especially if you want to share a list of games
- Will only show games that you have downloaded digitally and will not display any physical games

**2. My PlayStation Account**

You can visit [my.playstation.com](https://my.playstation.com/) and navigate to trophies tab. This page provides a slick interface that shows all of the games that you have played on your PSN account along with all of your trophies.

This page is semi-public, meaning that your friends or colleagues will need to log into their PSN account (or set one up) in order to view it.

**3. PSNProfile**

An non-Sony site I recommend is [PSNProfiles](https://psnprofiles.com/BTWondercricket). PSNProfiles has no affiliation with Sony or PlayStation, but provides a clean, public, and easy website where you can view all the games you played on your PSN account. This page provides very similar information to my.playstation.com, just laid out differently.

This website is free to use (but there is a premium version if you choose) and does not require you to log into your PSN account.

There is a delay on getting the information synced with your PSN account, which varies based on your account level (1 week for unregistered accounts, daily for registered accounts, every 6 hours for premium accounts)

Comment: Thanks - the games I've played is (to my shame) a very different list to the games I own, but it's a start!

Comment: @Grim... Yeah, games that you own vs games that you've played will be two different lists. Most places (aside from the download list, granite you've downloaded it) will only show games that you played at least once. You don't have to even play the game really for it to show up. Just opening and then closing out of it is enough

Answer (score 0):

Log into the [PSStore](https://store.playstation.com/en-gb/home/games) - there should be a list of games on there.

Answer (score 0):

Well for the full list of your online purchased games you can do as such:
As soon as you log in into your PS Store account you can call the following URL in another TAB:
[https://web.np.playstation.com/api/graphql/v1/op?operationName=getPurchasedGameList&variables={"isActive":true,"platform":["ps4","ps5"],"size":24,"start":0,"sortBy":"TITLE_NAME","sortDirection":"desc","subscriptionService":"NONE"}&extensions={"persistedQuery":{"version":1,"sha256Hash":"2c045408b0a4d0264bb5a3edfed4efd49fb4749cf8d216be9043768adff905e2"}}](https://web.np.playstation.com/api/graphql/v1/op?operationName=getPurchasedGameList&variables=%7B%22isActive%22:true,%22platform%22:%5B%22ps4%22,%22ps5%22%5D,%22size%22:24,%22start%22:0,%22sortBy%22:%22TITLE_NAME%22,%22sortDirection%22:%22desc%22,%22subscriptionService%22:%22NONE%22%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22:%7B%22version%22:1,%22sha256Hash%22:%222c045408b0a4d0264bb5a3edfed4efd49fb4749cf8d216be9043768adff905e2%22%7D%7D)

OBS: The size value you have to change to fit your whole library. In my case it was more than 200 games, so adjust accordinly.

Go then to https://www.jsonquerytool.com/
Select JSON Path Plus 4.0.
Copy the retrieved content from the URL you listed your games.
Type the following query in the Query box:
$[data].[purchasedTitlesRetrieve].[games]..name

Your full game list will be listed in the Output box.